# TSQL not returning DISTINCT Values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, distinct

I am trying to get only unique primary key values using DISTINCT but cannot figure out why DISTINCT is not working.  The TSQL below (Using Windows Azure SQL Server) is trying to identify duplicate addresses by looking at the first string of numeric values in the address field.  It is returning matches properly but just too many duplicate values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Id AS DinstinctID
    ,b.Id AS LeftID
    ,LEFT(b.StreetAddress, CHARINDEX(' ', b.StreetAddress))
    ,LEFT(a.StreetAddress, CHARINDEX(' ', a.StreetAddress))
FROM [User] a
JOIN [User] b ON b.Id != a.Id AND 
    LEFT(a.StreetAddress,CHARINDEX(' ', a.StreetAddress))  = 
       LEFT(b.StreetAddress,CHARINDEX(' ', b.StreetAddress)) 
    AND b.DateSubmitted >= DATEADD(day, -5, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Look carefully for leading or trailing spaces or unprintable characters. You can try concatenating your strings with something like '!' in front and back to see the spaces.

Comment: Cleaning it up now, still getting used to SO formatting sorry.

Comment: Are you **really sure** you want a Cartesian product wit the main diagonal (only) excluded?

Comment: Thanks Krishnraj!  That looks much better...

Comment: I am unsure what you're asking Pieter?

Comment: @KyleGMotion: Read the first term of you JOIN clause closely. Joins with a `!=` are immediately suspicious.

Comment: Gotcha Peter the only reason I don't think that is the case is because the field is a auto generated PK value.

Comment: Doing now @Pieter.  It was using a FROM clause but I read on a similar question to try a JOIN which yielded the exact same results.  Here is an image of the asp.net grid https://www.facebook.com/G23DS/photos/pcb.637158506420991/637158296421012/?type=1&theater

Comment: And the VS results https://www.facebook.com/G23DS/photos/pcb.637158506420991/637158416421000/?type=1&theater

Comment: It should be noted these are all in the same table so the != is meant to stop the statement from thinking 2 PK values that match are a "duplicate"

Comment: Try sorting your results by the address field.  Right now all you're looking for that's unique is the first word of the address, so any rows that have that match (but not the userid) will be returned.  From your screen grab, all of those rows are DISTINCT.

Comment: Trying now @Data ty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not very clear
Distinct is based on all columns
Distinct was giving the right answer
Since you have b.Id != a.Id all the rows returned are distinct
I think this is what you are looking for
There is not reason to return the same address in two columns

```
SELECT distinct a.Id AS DinstinctID
      ,LEFT(b.StreetAddress, CHARINDEX(' ', b.StreetAddress))
FROM [User] a
JOIN [User] b ON b.Id > a.Id 
     AND  LEFT(a.StreetAddress,CHARINDEX(' ', a.StreetAddress))  = 
          LEFT(b.StreetAddress,CHARINDEX(' ', b.StreetAddress)) 
     AND b.DateSubmitted >= DATEADD(day, -5, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) 
order by 2
```

Comment: That did the trick @Blam!  Sorry again for the poorly formed question I have learned much from this and will do better in future questions.  I need to study more about DISTINCT.  You da man!  Thanks to everyone else too...

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting the strings to binary and comparing that way. Would help you in discovering if any hidden characters are causing the join criteria to not act as you would expect.

Comment: I probably didn't explain it well but the field I want to be DISTINCT is the primary key IDENTITY (SMALLINT) field that is auto generated by the DB.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying @CoderKen.  I'll check that out.

Comment: Not you did not explain it very well.  Just a.ID unique?

Comment: Exactly @Blam.  Sorry for the confusion.  a.ID is what I am looking to get as DISTINCT values not the address.